# Wrapping a type alias in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to see if validate_convert is defined for the type specified.  Problem is I defined my type as an alias instead of wrapping it.  Now I have a lot of code that uses this type and it seems to me like wrapping it would require a lot of changes to use something like `value(U::UserID) = U.value`.

Do you see anyway of making this work but not match when `type=String` only when `type=UserID` or is there another solution?

```
UserID = String

function validate_convert(::Type{UserID}, input)::UserID
    parse(UserID, input)
end

type = UserID
hasmethod(validate_convert, Tuple{typeof(type),typeof(value)})
```

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to me like wrapping it would require a lot of changes to use something like `value(U::UserID) = U.value`.

[TypedDelegation.jl](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/TypedDelegation.jl):

> Easily apply functions onto fields.
> Use a struct's fields as operands for operations on values of that type.

You can make your type a wrapper type, and then use `@delegate_onefield` and `@delegate_onefield_astype` to forward calls on your `UserID` type to be calls on the wrapped `String`. `@delegate_onefield` will return what the call on the `String` returns as is, `@delegate_onefield_astype` is useful for methods that return a `String` but you want them to return a `UserID`.

Comment: This lib doesnt implement functions such as `==(::UserID, ::String)`

Answer (score 0):

Your type alias `UserID` is completely equivalent to `String`:

```
julia> UserID = String;

julia> UserID === String
true
```

So, no, there is no way to write a method that matches `UserID` but not `String`. Your options are to make `UserID` a struct that wraps a string (or an integer or whatever you need), or to just use plain old `String` for your user IDs. If you don't need to dispatch on the user ID, then it might make sense to just use strings for the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper types are a bit of a [problem](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37790). If you want `Wrapper{T}` to behave just like `T`, then you need to reimplement all the methods defined for `T`, which is unfortunate.

This may not be applicable for you, but if you're mainly interested in using these wrapper types inside structs you can hide some logic to wrap/unwrap the data transparently when it's accessed. As an example:

```
struct ValidatedField{Tag, T}
    val::T

    function ValidatedField{Tag, T}(val) where {Tag, T}
        vf = new{Tag, T}(val::T)
        (validate(vf) || throw(ArgumentError("Invalid: $val"))) && vf
    end
end

value(vf::ValidatedField) = vf.val
validate(vf::ValidatedField) = false

abstract type ValidatedRecord end

function Base.getproperty(vr::V, field::Symbol) where V <: ValidatedRecord
    f = getfield(vr, field)
    return f isa ValidatedField ? value(f) : f
end

function Base.setproperty!(vr::V, field::Symbol, val) where V <: ValidatedRecord
    T = fieldtype(V, field) 
    setfield!(vr, field, T <: ValidatedField ? T(val) : val)
end

UserID = ValidatedField{:UserId, String}
validate(u::UserID) = all(islowercase, value(u))

mutable struct User <: ValidatedRecord
    id::UserID # appears as a String but must be a valid UserID
    name::String # just a normal String

    function User(id, name)
        u = new()
        u.id, u.name = id, name
        return u
    end
end

user = User("foo", "Bob")
user.id # => "foo"
user.id = "Bar" # invalid
user.id = "bar" # valid
```